# Split a string tensor by whitespace keep the whitespace in output

Tags: string, tensorflow2.0

I would like to split a TensorFlow tensor by whitespace but want the whitespace also to be added in output.

```
Input = ['WE ARE ONE']
Output = ['WE',' ','ARE',' ','ONE']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using `regex_replace()`. Replace whitespace with `'< <'` and then split the string by `'<'`

```
a=tf.constant(['WE ARE ONE'])
a=tf.strings.regex_replace(a,' ', '< <')
a =tf.strings.split(a,sep='l')
```